# problems on dynamic dropdown lists

Tags: php, dynamic, html.dropdownlistfor

I am currently working on a a drop down list which fetch all college names in my college table I was wondering how can I make a another drop down list in which it fetches all departments in the currently selected collage name without using a form (for the page must not reload during the process.

There are two tables involved one is for the departments and other is for college

this is a sample code from the first drop down list.

```
<tr>
<th class="text-success">College:</th>
  <td>
    <select name = "AdminUpdateCollageID" class ="bg-info" name>
    <option>Please choose a college </option> 
    <option>
      <?php
         $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM colleges")
         or die("NO table selected" . mysql_error());
         while($rw = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         echo $rw['College_Name'] ; //this displays the values in the dropdown

                         }
?> 
 </option></select>  

 </td> 
 </tr>
```

I'l Try to upload the two tables this is the first time I post a question on stackoverflow also I am still a student please bear with me any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to read up on AJAX as an approach to solving this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are a student, I won't give you a directly answer - I'll give you sources which you will need to read and get the solutions by yourself:

1. JQUERY - http://www.jquery.com
2. AJAX - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

A BONUS TO FIX PHP:

3. PDO - http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers
4. http://www.phptherightway.com

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to send ajax request from here [ajax request to other php page and get result](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) or from here [ajax example with jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)  or 
you can view the example here if it will help [Php dependent dropdown with ajax](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
<select name = "AdminUpdateCollageID" class ="bg-info" name>
<option value='selected' selected>Please choose a college </option> 

  <?php
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM colleges")
     or die("NO table selected" . mysql_error());
     while($rw = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
     echo "<option value=".$rw[id].">" . $rw['College_Name'] "</option>"; //this displays the values in the dropdown

                     }
```

?>

This should works!
Every option has it's result. You can't insert all results in one single option ;)
I don't know your DB but you can put in each option value, the id of each college, to recognize it better!

Take care ;)